# SQL UPDATE command don't work but no error messages

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio, sql-update

When I'm trying to update my database it don't seem to save my changes I'm trying to do. I don't get any error messages of any kind.

My code in VS looks like this:

```
    public void Update(Resturang Resturang)
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Resturanger SET Namn = @Namn, Stad = @Stad, PostNr = @PostNr, Adress = @Adress, OrgNr = @OrgNr WHERE Id = @Id;", con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Namn", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Resturang.Namn;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Stad", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Resturang.Stad;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@PostNr", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Resturang.PostNr;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Adress", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Resturang.Adress;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@OrgNr", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Resturang.OrgNr;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Resturang.Id;
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

I know that my parameters get their expected values but it won't be saved in my SQL Server database.

I don't know why my code don't work, anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Ypu can use sql-profiler and watch the query set to server

Comment: Is this code being executed at all?  What are the runtime values when that happens?  Are there any matching records for the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: I would ideally do two things, one debug, which i guess you might have done it already. Other check sql profiler to see whats happening with this query execution on db end.

Comment: What value does `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` return?

Comment: informations not enough

Comment: is there a record with `Id = @Id` ?

Comment: be sure the ID provided to @Id exists.  If that's not the problem, you would look at con.

Comment: Can you show us your **connection string**, please?

Comment: are you actually looking at the right database? (in case you have multiple databases running).

Comment: I know the connectionstring is working since other commands to the database works.

yes im also sure im looking at the right database, only have this one.

Comment: I have found the problem now! Thnaks to @tdbeckett i fond that the ID was lost in an action before the one that executes the update.

Thanks all who took time to give me advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this:

1. the connector works?
2. try to execute a simple update (not with parameter)
3. check all type of the variables before update

thanks

Comment: I have found the problem now! Thnaks to @tdbeckett i fond that the ID was lost in an action before the one that executes the update. Thanks all who took time to give me advice!